# На какое минимальное количество букв можно сокращать?

Tags: сокращения

Мне кажется, что на одну букву сокращать недопустимо, на две тоже не стоит, на три — ещё куда ни шло. Действительно, когда остаётся дописать одну или две буквы, почему бы не дописать их или не сократить раньше, если это в словосочетании из сокращений.

И вообще, согласятся ли со мной другие в том, что сокращать одно слово, при том что вокруг по тексту нету близко сокращений и слово не такое, которое принято часто сокращать (например, см., пр., др.), — это нонсенс и режет глаз?

Самый простой пример сокращения на две буквы это отбрасывание окончаний *ой, ий, ая* и др. Был вопрос, например, как сокращать "русский язык", и большинство отмело вариант *"русск.",* наверно, в том числе прислушиваюсь к тому же внутреннему ощущению. Согласны ли вы со мной, что таких отбрасываний окончаний следует избегать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не оговорили самое главное. Где сокращать, кому сокращать, зачем сокращать? 
Если это Ваш личный конспект лекций, сокращайте как угодно, хоть стенографируйте. В словарях и справочниках, а заодно - и некоторых учебниках, допустимы любые сокращения, если они приведены где-нибудь в одном месте. В других технических текстах сокращения допускаются только в таблицах.

Ну и есть еще общепринятые сокращения и обозначения физических единиц и аббревиатуры (включая "и т. п.", "и т. д."), которые в общем-то допустимы в любом тексте, кроме художественного и детского.

Другими словами выбирать-то не из чего. Все официальные сокращения давным давно известны и закреплены, а другие можно использовать только в личных целях, тогда на них, естественно, и правил нет.

Comment: Спасибо! Конечно, я имел в виду текст, написанный для всех, напр, форумы, этот сайт. А что такое т. и. п.? Просто возник вопрос в т. ч. и потому, что на этом сайте бывает, что читаешь чей-то ответ, всё написано гладко, полными словами (не считая и т. д., т. е., в т. ч., п. ч., т. к. и других подобных), и вдруг встречаешь какое-нибудь "предл." среди полных слов. Хотел убедиться, что это не очень хорошо.

Comment: Я, конечно, понимаю, что т. к., т. е., п. ч. и ещё к.-то не общепринятые, но мне кажется, что это не так плохо по сравнению с тем, о чём я говорил. Сам так иногда пишу. Кстати, к.-то сейчас написал, п. ч. спешу, в вопросе и ответе не стал бы так писать (а это ведь комментарий).

Comment: "т. и. п." - это что-то очень специфическое. Теория и практика? вряд ли её стоит сокращать так.

Comment: Явно что-то другое. Да и перед И бы тогда точка не нужна была.

Comment: Братцы, это опечатка. Уже не помню что хотел написать, пусть будет "и т. д."